# can "take" be used in the continuous tenses?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Kid A and B are fighting over the toy. Both hands of A and B are on the toys.

[image]

Is it correct for the kid A to say "**Mom, he is taking my toy**"

But that situation is rare, normally, it will take 1 or 2 seconds to take something.

Say, B already took the toy of A. Right at that moment, is it correct to say "**he is taking my toy**"?

Comment: Of course it is _grammatically_ correct to use the continuous tense of _take_. Whether it's appropriate in these circumstances is for your child to decide! They could say "She's _trying to_ take my toy away!"